# Using backslashes in vim abbreviations

Tags: vim

I want to be able to write `\bit` and have it expand to something in vim. How do I encode a backslash in the left-hand side of an abbreviation, though?

I tried all of these:

```
:iab \bit replacement_text
:iab <Bslash>bit replacement_text
:iab <bs>bit replacement_text
```

but got `E474: Invalid argument` for all of these.

The `map_backslash` help-topic suggests `<Bslash>`, but this doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Aaarrgghh!  It's a cracker.  Your <Bslash>, I learned, is a {rhs} thing.  In the {lhs}, "\b" (w/o quotes) works, but the E474 is there when a second char is added "\bi".  "\\" and "\\b" are acceptable, but "\\bi" is not.  '"\bit"' (w/o outer single quotes) works, but the double quotes are part of the ab.  Like I said, "Aaarrgghh!"  +1

Comment: if you stick this in an answer @Ewan I can vote this up, and it will be easier to see the quotes. This is interesting stuff...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can define your abbreviation on "bit", and then test if it is preceded by "", if so, return the new text, or "bit" otherwise.

```
function! s:Expr(default, repl) expr
  if getline('.')[col('.')-2]=='\'
    return "\<bs>".a:repl
  else
    return a:default
  endif
endfunction

:inoreab bit <c-r>=<sid>Expr('bit', 'foobar')<cr>
```

That's the kind of tricks I used in [MapNoContext()](https://github.com/LucHermitte/lh-brackets/blob/master/autoload/lh/map.vim#L180).

EDIT: see [:h abbreviations](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/cgi-bin/help?tag=abbreviations) for the reasons why what you asked can't be achieved directly.

EDIT2: It can be easily encapsulated this way:

```
function! s:DefIab(nore, ...) abort
  let opt = ''
  let i = 0
  while i != len(a:000)
    let arg = a:000[i]
    if arg !~? '<buffer>\|<silent>'
      break
    endif
    let opt .= ' '.arg
    let i += 1
  endwhile

  if i+2 != len(a:000)
    throw "Invalid number of arguments"
  endif
  let lhs = a:000[i]
  let rhs = a:000[i+1]

  exe 'i'.a:nore.'ab'.opt.' '.lhs.' <c-r>=<sid>Expr('.string(lhs).', '.string(rhs).')<cr>'
endfunction

command! -nargs=+ InoreabBSlash call s:DefIab('nore', <f-args>)
```

And used with a simple:

```
InoreabBSlash <buffer> locbit foobar
```

or

```
InoreabBSlash bit foobar
```

Answer (score 3):

I suggest using backslash on both sides, vim is happy that way:

```
inoreabbr \bit\ replacement_text
```

Note that I am using the "nore" version of abbr, better to be clear if you don't intend a recursive expansion. I have been using the below abbreviations for a long time and they work great:

```
inoreabbr \time\ <C-R>=strftime("%d-%b-%Y @ %H:%M")<CR>
inoreabbr \date\ <C-R>=strftime("%d-%b-%Y")<CR>
```

Comment: Creative alternative. The trailing backslash turns this into an allowed _non-id_ abbreviation.

Answer (score 3):

```
:set iskeyword+=\
```

in vimrc_tex (or just vimrc) works perfectly.

Comment: This works perfectly! Does it cause any issues elsewhere?

Comment: This has side effects, so see `:help 'isk'` to see if this is acceptable for you.

Answer (score 1):

you could

```
   inoremap \bit replacementtext
```

Also if you dont like the lag an alternative leader like backtick ` (above the tab for me)

```
   :iab `f foobar
```

if you are not using them in your code often

Comment: This would work, but not exactly the same way. There'd be an annoying pause after every \ waiting for the rest of it. I don't quite see a way around that though.

Comment: I have this for a couple of imaps (using <cr>= for some function processing) you get over the pause (it forces you just type faster :)

Answer (score 1):

You can only use a backslash as a prefix for an abbreviation if it's only got a single character following it, so `:iab \b replacementtext` will work.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried several escape sequences to prepend my abbreviations with a comma to no avail (`\,`, `<,>`, `<comma>`) to get something like `:iab ,myabbr`. A proposed solution was appending a double comma at the end of the string, testing it didn't feel natural.

It might not be a "programming" solution but the work around that ultimately gave me piece of mind was to add a `c` that stands for comma at the beginning, like this `:iab cmyabbr` this way preserves the thought process which is important to me to keep consistency across the other applications in my OS where employ text replacements like `,myabbr`.

If this simple approach works for you I'd suggest to add something like `:iab bsmyabbr` where `bs` is the mnemonics for the intended backslash, fortunately, if by any chance do you happen to encounter a string that **contains** the said abbreviation it won't trigger it, it only expands in an exact match circumventing the restrictions previously explained in [:h abbreviations](https://vimhelp.org/map.txt.html#abbreviations).

Hope it helps.