# Setting Vi abbreviation that includes special character

Tags: vim, vi

How to set the abbreviation for a specific word that contains special character like ":,;'." etc., for instance, I want to set an abbreviation for std::map to std::map

```
:ab std::map std::map<string,int>
```

is not working

Answer (score 1):

The abbreviation trigger text has restrictions: it has to be of either *full-id*, *end-id*, or *non-id* type (basically, which characters are *keywords*; see `:help abbreviations` for details).

For the C / C++ filetypes, the colon `:` normally is **not part of `'iskeyword'`**, that's causing the `E474` error. As it's not recommended to mess with that setting (it affects navigation, syntax highlighting, etc.), you have to drop / replace it from the abbreviation:

```
:ab stdmap std::map<string,int>
```

Comment: Thanks [Ingo Karkat](http://stackoverflow.com/users/813602/ingo-karkat) for the info.

Answer (score 0):

The solution I proposed in [Using backslashes in vim abbreviations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1677575/using-backslashes-in-vim-abbreviations/1680834#1680834) should be adaptable to your case. You will have to adapt the test `getline('.')[col('.')-2]=='\'` to something like `getline('.')[:col('.')-2] =~ '.*std::$'` (untested)

But, honestly, you should consider using a snippet engine instead, there are plenty.

Comment: I thought about the snippet workaround, too, but: At least the original snipMate doesn't accept colons, neither, and this would then require manual triggering, not the automatic replacement of abbreviations.

Comment: Well, I'm still maintaining mu-template (which can look back for `\k\+`, or WORD depending on the (parametrizable) trigger used), I have no idea what snipMate (and sons) can or cannot do exactly -- regarding the colons, it would have be tricky to support it with mu-template as well. ^^  

Regarding abbreviations that do not need triggers, yes and no. Most of the time we hit `space` to trigger them. With snippets (at least with mu-template), we don't need to type everything. `ma<C-space>` would have worked as well as `map<C-space>`.