# How to abbrev "|" char?

Tags: vim

In my vimrc, I am making a few `iabbrev`-s. All others like `>=`, `==` work well, except `||` and `|||`.

Using `||` or `|||` directly in `.vimrc` gives me errors. Escaping them to `\|` or `<bar>` did not work.

Please help.

---

To be more specific, I have the following:

```
iabbrev <buffer> || ∨
iabbrev <buffer> ||| ⫴
iabbrev <buffer> alpha α
```

Only the last line of alpha works. And it is working as, in insert mode, after inputting "alpha", I press Space, then I have "α " in buffer.

Comment: possibly the same as this one? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1677575/using-backslashes-in-vim-abbreviations/1680834#1680834

Comment: @DoktorOSwaldo the root problem is the same but, given OP's exact question, I remember having given better answers elsewhere, here, it'd be better to have an `imap`ping that checks its context

Comment: @LucHermitte Of course I check *all* of your past answers before posting a comment, but unfortunaly that was the most fitting I found ;-) Would be interesting to here the whole usecase here to judge what would be the best solution. But yes, `imap` sounds reasonable.

Comment: @DoktorOSwaldo I can stop searching then ;) It could have been on vi.SE or on reddit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Abbreviations are designed in such a way that they work very well with keyword characters, but not so much with other characters. On the other hand, when we start to type characters that can appear in the beginning of mappings, nothing is displayed: it's not really ergonomic to solve abbreviation like expansions in insert mode.

In that case, the solution implemented by IMAP plugin (also shipped with vim-latex) is probably the better: define a mapping on the last character of the *left hand side* sequence you wish to type, analyse the context and expand in consequence. The difficulty is that a same character may end 42 different abbreviations. That's where IMAP plugin enters as it takes care of this.

Note that if you expect to expand `||` and `|||` to different things, well good luck.

Given a mapping on `|` that analyses its context, If I found what `||` is expanded into before the cursor, I'll know that what was typed is a third pipe, and thus I'll remove and replace everything with the new stuff associated to `|||`.

Note to have a more precise answer, you'll need to give us more details.

EDIT: Given the specification, we cannot

- have two abbreviations as the third pipe type triggers the `||` abbreviation
- have an abbreviation on `||` and a contextual mapping on `|` as the mapping neutralizes the abbreviation

So, I'd proceed this way with only a single mapping

```
inoremap <buffer> <expr> \| get({'\|': '<bs>∨', '∨': '<bs>⫴'}, matchstr(getline('.')[:col('.')], '.$'), '\|')
```

where:

1. I define a dictionary that associates a context to what it'll become ; which changes the replacement semantics from `||` -> `∨` and `|||` -> `⫴` to `||` -> `∨` and `∨|` -> `⫴`.
2. I extract the last character before the cursor (it should be doable with a single call to `matchstr()` with the column-number-pattern)
3. I inject that contextual character into the dictionary to see how it should be replaced, and if that contextual character is unregistered, we simply inject a pipe.

Comment: Thanks. I thought my problem was just a syntax limitation of vimrc. Actually, I am not quite following what you said. In my vim env, the replacement occurs when I input a space (after the "||" (if it works)). Why it needs to analyse the context to see if I want to replace "||" or "|||"?

Comment: Could you show us what abbreviations you would have liked to define?

Comment: First of all, it works great. But different with other abbrev-s, "||" and "|||" are replaced right in place (while typing). Extra space after is not needed.

Comment: Also, in this way, seems like I cannot use "ctrl-v space" to "not abbrev" for just this time.

Comment: It would be `^v|` instead.