# Is it possible to include a carriage return in a vim abbreviation id?

Tags: vim

This is what I have currently, but it doesn't work.

```
:ab name<cr> NAME<cr>
```

So

> name
> hello

should become

> NAME
> hello

I want to be able to type a name in a line, and have that name automatically be turned to uppercase form. It should only do this when it is by itself on a line and if a carriage return follows the name.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is almost the same as the one described in [Using backslashes in vim abbreviations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1677575/using-backslashes-in-vim-abbreviations)

The difference is that the *incompatible* character is not leading, but terminating the abbreviation. The solution is instead to have a mapping on `<cr>`, test that what is before the cursor (`expand('<word>')` should be enough), and if this matches what your are looking for, erase that text, and insert it upper-cased.

Comment: Ended up creating a plugin to basically do what I want https://github.com/Tinkergod/vim-fountain-tools